# Django multiple table join on using ORM

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-related-manager

I am trying to join multiple table using django ORM .i have tried several different way but no luck.

```
from django.db import models
from compositefk.fields import CompositeForeignKey, CompositeOneToOneField

class Company(models.Model):
    code = models.DecimalField(db_column='Code', max_digits=38, decimal_places=0)   
    srccode  = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='SrcCode')   
    est = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Est')   
    rownum = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='RowNum')  

    class Meta:
       manage = False
       unique_together = (('code', 'srccode'),)
       db_table = 'Company'  

class Floor(models.Model):
    code = models.DecimalField(db_column='Code', max_digits=38, decimal_places=0)   
    srccode  = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='SrcCode') 
    depcode = models.DecimalField(db_column='DepCode', max_digits=38, decimal_places=0)    
    depsrccode  = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='Depsrccode')   
    floorname  = models.CharField(db_column='FloorName')   
    rownum = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='RowNum')
    company = CompositeForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_fields={'code':'code','srccode': 'srccode'})
    department= CompositeOneToOneField(Department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_fields={'depcode':'depcode','depsrccode': 'depsrccode'})   

    class Meta:
        manage = False
        unique_together = (('depcode', 'depsrccode','floorname'),)
        db_table = 'floor'

class SubCompany(models.Model):
    code = models.DecimalField(db_column='Code', max_digits=38, decimal_places=0)   
    srccode  = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='SrcCode')
    subname  = models.CharField(db_column='SubName')   
    rownum = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='RowNum')
    location = models.CharField(db_column='Location')
    department = models.CharField(db_column='Department')
    company = CompositeForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_fields={'code':'code','srccode': 'srccode'})

    class Meta:
        manage = False
        unique_together = (('code', 'srccode','subname','rownum'),)
        db_table = 'SubCompany'
```

basically i am trying to get data as per below row sql

```
SELECT Location, Department, Subname, t.* from [Floor] t join [SubCompany] s on t.code = s.code and t.srccode = s.srccode;"
```

what is the equilant Django Orm of above SQL query.?
is there any alternative solution apart from raw sql in django.?
Thanks

Comment: The ORM automatically joins tables if there are [relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) defined between the models, but you cannot do joins of your choosing unfortunately.

Comment: thanks Endre . how should i approach this issue .? do we have any other alternative.?

Comment: The (better) alternative is to read up on relationship modelling and create properly defined and linked Django models. Then you can also throw out the `CompositeForeignKey`s. Try to find examples of how more complex systems are modelled in larger projects.